# Cannot play game on Xbox 360 without Live?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare

I got this game second hand and - having no Xbox Live (it doesn't seem to work for my console where I am at) - I can't even play. A message says: "Connection! Your gamer profile doesn't have these privileges to access functions of Xbox Live." In short, this means I cannot ever play this game without Live? Is there no way around it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Xbox Live is a required service if you wish to play a multiplayer game like Garden Warfare. If you are in China, Xbox Live on 360 is not supported. You can see a full list of the supported countries/regions here: https://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/countries

You can try setting your console to one of these regions to gain access to the service, but it's not something i have experience with.